# Sound Blaster 16 sound card in assembly x86 - reading from ADC

Tags: audio, assembly, soundcard

I have a problem with reading samples form ADC of Sound Blaster 16 sound card.

Environment: I am working on Windows XP 32-bit host on Windows 8.1 64-bit via Oracle VirtualBox 5.0.10. I am emulating my assembly program with DOSBox. I am writing program in assembly x86 and compiling it using ML.

To do: I would like to read sampled sound from ADC of sound card from my computer. Sound should be delivered by microphone (built in my laptop) or line-in.

Problem: When I am trying to read sample from ADC, I always get the same data. It seems that I am reading data from ADC, which is not filled by samples of sound delivered to computer by microphone or line-in. Perhaps my program can't "catch" sound from microphone.

Additional information:

1. Both in Windows 8.1 and Windows XP microphone is working. I checked this in Control Panel. Also, using Windows Sound Recorder works fine on both OS.
2. As I previously mentioned, probably I don't turn on microphone in my application and I can't "catch" sound from the microphone. Now, to read samples, I am using following algorithm:

   ```
   1. Write 20h to DSP.
       a. Read data from 22Ch (my sound card start from 220h, I checked it and it works - see below) until the most significant bit will be 0.
       b. Write 20h to 22Ch.
   2. Read value from DSP.
       a. Read data from 22Eh until the most significant bit will be 1.
       b. Read data from 22Ah.
   ```

Also, at the very beginning I am doing reset of sound card and turning SPEAKER (?) on (by writing D1h to 22Ch).

The most important thing is that I AM ABLE TO SEND SOUND TO SOUND CARD. Yes, I am sending rectangular signal do DSP and I am getting noise in my speakers. I am using following algorithm:

```
1. Write 10h to DSP (to 22Ch, procedure as above).
2. Write data byte (F0h) to DSP (to 22Ch).
3. Repeat for the second tone (1Ah to 22Ch).
```

Also, I am doing reset of sound card and turing speaker on, but - what is a bit interesting - it doesn't matter. If I don't reset the card and I don't turn the speaker on, I am still able to hear noise after sending data to DAC.

So, In my opinion it's everything OK with virtual machine, soundcard etc. and the only mistake is that I can't capture sound from microphone.

There is a piece of code which I use to read samples from ADC:

```
    readSample proc

        ; Write 20h to DSP
        pollWriteBuffer:
            mov dx, 22Ch
            in al, dx
            and al, 10000000B
            cmp al, 0
            jne pollWriteBuffer

        mov dx, 22Ch
        mov al, 20h
        out dx, al

        ; Read value from DSP
        pollReadBuffer:
            mov dx, 22Eh
            in al, dx
            and al, 10000000B
            cmp al, 10000000B
            jne pollReadBuffer

        mov dx, 22Ah
        in al, dx

            ;--- TEST ---;
                mov ah, 02h
                mov dl, al
                int 21h
            ;------------;

        ret

    readSample endp
```

Note that I would like to avoid using DMA access if it is possible. I have read tones of literature and I can't deal with my problem. If you know why I can't read samples from ADC, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Eliminate variables. First verify your configuration is valid: find some DOS program that can record from the SoundBlaster card, or loop back the mic to the speakers. Then you know everything but your code is working. For bonus points, reverse engineer said software comparing what they're doing to what you're doing.

Comment: Looping back microphone to speakers is meaningless - as I mentioned, I always get the same value reading from ADC. Moreover, as You can see, I am printing this char on stdout and I get that this value is always 127 (dec). So, looping back microphone to speakers results only in two "beats". There is no wave, signal is constant, so I can't hear anything interesting. I will try to find some program on the web which records from Sound Blaster 16.

Comment: I'm saying find *another program* to do this. One that you know works.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't select the microphone for input to the ADC.

The Sound Blaster 16 has an input mixer and an output mixer.  The ADC digitizes values output from the input mixer.  The input mixer can receive signals from the microphone, CD player, line input, or MIDI output, but there's a switch between each of those and the mixer.  To record from the microphone, you must close the switch that connects the microphone to the input mixer.

There is also a gain control for the mixer output to the ADC, and a gain control for the microphone input to the mixer.  If either of those is turned all the way down, the ADC won't receive any signal from the microphone.